# Changing contents of vertex with JGraphT

Tags: java, jgrapht

Is there a method to change the contents of a vertex while keeping all its edges. I couldn't find one but it seems like something that would be provided.

Answer (score 1):

JGraphT has no method for replacing a vertex. You can use this to do what you want:

```
public static <V, E> void replaceVertex(Graph<V, E> graph, V vertex, V replace) {
    graph.addVertex(replace);
    for (E edge : graph.outgoingEdgesOf(vertex)) graph.addEdge(replace, graph.getEdgeTarget(edge), edge);
    for (E edge : graph.incomingEdgesOf(vertex)) graph.addEdge(graph.getEdgeSource(edge), replace, edge);
    graph.removeVertex(vertex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by changing contents of a vertex? Vertices are made with generics, which means you can put just any object there, which means it's up to you to provide a method to replace the contents of this object, if it is not immutable.  Or do you want to put completely a new object there (completely new vertex) and save all relations of the old one? Then you would probably have to find edges with this vertex (`java.util.Set<E> edgesOf(V vertex)`), remove them (`boolean removeEdge(E e)`), and replace with new ones, containing the new vertex (`E addEdge(V sourceVertex, V targetVertex)`).